# Convert Message to Job to make it Spring Integration with Batch Processing

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-batch, spring-dsl

I am trying to process a series of files using Spring Integration in a batch fashion. I have this very old xml which tries to convert the messages into jobs

```
    <int:transformer ref="messageToJobTransformer"/>
    <batch-int:job-launching-gateway job-launcher="jobLauncher"/>
```

The `messageToJobTransformer` is a class which can convert a Message into a Job. The problem is I don't know where this file is now neither I want a xml config. I want it to be pure Java DSL. Here is my simple config.

```
return IntegrationFlows.from(Files.inboundAdapter(directory)
                    .preventDuplicates()
                    .patternFilter("*.txt")))
                    .handle(jobLaunchingGw())                       
                    .get();
```

And here is my bean for the gateway.

```
@Autowired
private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

@Bean
public MessageHandler jobLaunchingGw() {
    return new JobLaunchingGateway(jobLauncher);   
}
```

EDIT:Updating the Batch Config class.

```
@Configuration
    @EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig

{

@Autowired
private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

@Autowired
private StepBuilderFactory steps;




@Bean
        public ItemReader<String> reader(@Value({jobParameters['input.file.name']}") String filename) throws MalformedURLException
    {
        FlatFileItemReader<String> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<String>();       
        return reader;
    }
@Bean
public Job job() throws MalformedURLException
{
    return jobs.get("job").start(step()).build();
}

@Bean
public Step step() throws MalformedURLException
{
    return steps.get("step").<String, String> chunk(5).reader(reader())
    .writer(writer()).build();
}

@Bean
public ItemWriter<String> writer(@Value("#{jobParameters['input.file.name']}")
{
    FlatFileItemWriter writer = new FlatFileItemWriter();
    return writer;
}



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't clear. The `JobLaunchingGateway` expects `JobLaunchRequest` as a `payload`.

Since your Integration Flow begins from the `Files.inboundAdapter(directory)`, I can assume that you that you have there some Job definitions. So, what you need here is some class which can parse the file and return `JobLaunchRequest`.

Something like this from the Spring Batch [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/springBatchIntegration.html):

```
public class FileMessageToJobRequest {
    private Job job;
    private String fileParameterName;

    public void setFileParameterName(String fileParameterName) {
        this.fileParameterName = fileParameterName;
    }

    public void setJob(Job job) {
        this.job = job;
    }

    @Transformer
    public JobLaunchRequest toRequest(Message<File> message) {
        JobParametersBuilder jobParametersBuilder =
            new JobParametersBuilder();

        jobParametersBuilder.addString(fileParameterName,
            message.getPayload().getAbsolutePath());

        return new JobLaunchRequest(job, jobParametersBuilder.toJobParameters());
    }
}
```

After the definition that class as a `@Bean` you can use it from the `.transform()` EIP-method just before your `.handle(jobLaunchingGw())`.

**UPDATE**

```
@Bean
public FileMessageToJobRequest fileMessageToJobRequest(Job job) {
     FileMessageToJobRequest fileMessageToJobRequest = new FileMessageToJobRequest();
     fileMessageToJobRequest.setJob(job);
     fileMessageToJobRequest.setfileParameterName("file");
     return fileMessageToJobRequest;
}
...

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flowToBatch(FileMessageToJobRequest fileMessageToJobRequest) {

      return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Files.inboundAdapter(directory)
                    .preventDuplicates()
                    .patternFilter("*.txt")))
            .transform(fileMessageToJobRequest)
            .handle(jobLaunchingGw())                       
                    .get();

}
```

Comment: oh that did not help.Basically I am polling a directory and processing the files in batch.The problem with the above code is I am not able to see the job because the job would be created in the BatchConfig class.If it happens before I am getting an exception unable to read exception, if it happens after, Job is not visible.I think I am at a point that there is noway I can do this with Spring Integration Java DSL.Either I have to choose batch and XML  for Spring DSL or completely drop Spring Integration

Comment: ??? Not sure what is `BatchConfig page`, but you always can inject one bean into another - `@Autowired`. Share more config on the matter, e.g. for that `messageToJobTransformer`.

Comment: My bad should have written it as BatchConfig class.Updated the same

Comment: OK. What is the problem to inject that your `job()` bean in to the `FileMessageToJobRequest` component ?

Comment: Where should the transformer method go? Should it be in my config class? Initially I kept it in the seperate class as in FileMessageToJobRequest but since job was not visible I moved the transformer method to my config class.For some reason I am getting exceptions.

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer. If everything is going to be a single application context, you can inject and autowire everything what you need.

Comment: Everything looks good except now I need to access the file name in the batch for which I am accessing from the job parameter EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'